# unable to infer type in flatMap

Tags: swift, combine

*NetworkManager* class has *fetchData* generic function for fetching data from Internet.

```
class NetworkManager {
    
    func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<T, ErrorType> {
        URLSession
            .shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap { data, _ in
                return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            }
            .mapError { error -> ErrorType in
                switch error {
                case let urlError as URLError:
                    switch urlError.code {
                    case .notConnectedToInternet, .networkConnectionLost, .timedOut:
                        return .noInternetConnection
                    case .cannotDecodeRawData, .cannotDecodeContentData:
                        return .empty
                    default:
                        return .general
                    }
                default:
                    return .general
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

}
```

In *HomeRepositoryImpl* class I am trying to get data from specific url with *AnyPublisher<[CountryDayOneResponse], ErrorType>* return value. I wanted to sort responed array, so I used *flatMap* on *NetworkManager* like this:

```
func getCountryStats(for countryName: String) -> AnyPublisher<[CountryDayOneResponse], ErrorType> {
    let url = RestEndpoints.countryStats(countryName: countryName).endpoint()

    return NetworkManager().fetchData(url: url)
        .flatMap { result -> AnyPublisher<[CountryDayOneResponse], ErrorType> in
            switch result {
            case .success(var response):
                let filteredCountry = Array(response.sorted(by: {$0.date > $1.date}))
                response = filteredCountry
                return response
            case .failure(let error):
                return error
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But I am getting *Unable to infer type of a closure parameter 'result' in the current context* error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in your code... you haven't told it what `result` is. Even reading it as a human I can't tell what it is supposed to be.

Your `fetchData` function returns an `AnyPublisher` of generic type `T`.

Your `getCountryStats` function takes that generic type `T` into a `flatMap` function and returns an `AnyPublisher` of type `[CountryDayOneResponse]`.

But at no point do you tell it what `T` is. You don't even tell it what `result` is. Only the output of the `flatMap` function.

What is the type of `result` expected to be?

### Edit after comment.

If you want your `result` to be `[CountryOneDayResponse]` then this code will do...

```
func getCountryStats(for countryName: String) -> AnyPublisher<[CountryDayOneResponse], ErrorType> {
    let url = RestEndpoints.countryStats(countryName: countryName).endpoint()

    let publisher: AnyPublisher<[CountryDayOneResponse], ErrorType> = NetworkManager().fetchData(url: url)

    return publisher
        .flatMap{ Just(Array($0.sorted(by: {$0.date > $1.date}))) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

You don't need to switch on the result like you are doing in the `flatMap` as the `flatMap` will only be entered if the publisher returns a non-error. So you can treat the input of the `flatMap` as the success type of the publisher `[CountryOneDayResponse]`.

Comment: I tried to transform result to be AnyPublisher<[CountryDayOneResponse], ErrorType> so I could use switch statement. 
So i tried another way....I added  let publisher: AnyPublisher<[CountryDayOneResponse], ErrorType> = RestManager().fetchData(url: url), and I am returning publisher with .map returning filteredCountry and .mapError returning error with .eraseToAnyPublisher().

Comment: @MatejMatukovic I made an update that should work for you.